# Events for SELECT tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've written the following code, to enter a date:

```
<body>
<form name="insert" action="history.php" method="POST">
    <h1>HISTORY<h1>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
            DAY:
            <select>
                
                <option value="-1">Day:<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
            </select> 
            </td>
            
            <td>
            MONTH:
            <select>
                <option value="-1">Month:</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option></select>
            </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
            YEAR :
            <select>
            <option value="-1">Year:</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1930">1930</option><option value="1929">1929</option><option value="1928">1928</option><option value="1927">1927</option><option value="1926">1926</option><option value="1925">1925</option><option value="1924">1924</option><option value="1923">1923</option><option value="1922">1922</option><option value="1921">1921</option><option value="1920">1920</option><option value="1919">1919</option><option value="1918">1918</option><option value="1917">1917</option><option value="1916">1916</option><option value="1915">1915</option><option value="1914">1914</option><option value="1913">1913</option><option value="1912">1912</option><option value="1911">1911</option><option value="1910">1910</option><option value="1909">1909</option><option value="1908">1908</option><option value="1907">1907</option><option value="1906">1906</option><option value="1905">1905</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" class="abc" value="GO!!"><br>
</form>
</body>
```

How can I know, whether the value in a select menu is NULL or not? What event should I call and how can I do this? Please help me!

Comment: do you want to validate if the user has chosen day,month and year on submit action?

Answer (score 1):

you can write java script's change event like,

```
$( function(){

   $("form > select").change(function(){
      //you can write code to check the value of select here

         if($(this).val() == "some value")
         {
           //some prcessing
         }
   });
});
```

Comment: as wel, give the names to select so that you can identify which select box is triggered.

Comment: I think OP is looking for vanilla JS, not jQuery.